# Error (-215) while performing CLAHE on images with python

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, spyder

The following is the code i had entered in the Spyder Environment :

```
import os 
import cv2
import numpy as np
path1="E:\\academic\\FINAL YR PROJ\\PROJECT_DATASETS\\floyd_jan\\dr"
path2="E:\\academic\\FINAL YR PROJ\\PROJECT_DATASETS\\floyd_jan\\greendr"
names=[]
names=os.listdir(path1)
for i in names:
 bgr = cv2.imread(path1+"\\"+i,1)
 green = bgr[: , : , 1]
 lab = cv2.cvtColor(green, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
 lab_planes = cv2.split(lab)
 clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0,tileGridSize=(8,8))

 lab_planes[0] = clahe.apply(lab_planes[0])
 lab = cv2.merge(lab_planes)
 bgr = cv2.cvtColor(lab, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
 cv2.imwrite(path2+"\\"+i,bgr)
```

I am getting the following error on running the code :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 8, in 
>       lab = cv2.cvtColor(green, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
>
> error:
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:10724:
>   error: (-215) (scn == 3 || scn == 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth ==
>   CV_32F) in function cv::cvtColor

Unable to figure out the solution!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the part where you are calling the color-space conversion function

```
green = bgr[: , : , 1]
lab = cv2.cvtColor(green, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
```

You are using a gray-scale (single channel) image `green` to perform a color-space conversion (`cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB`) which is intended for color images (3 channels). 
What you should be doing instead is to use `bgr` in place of `green` as an input for `cv2.cvtColor`.

```
lab = cv2.cvtColor(bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
```

Comment: Yes, I get it what you intend to say, but I want to work with green channel alone and not the RGB image, in the sense that I want to perform image processing techniques on green channel image only.
In that case what should I edit in the code.. I basically want to perform CLAHE on the green image.

Comment: @KshitijZutshi... Well, if you want to use only the green channel ,there is no need to convert color space and split the channels of LAB image. Just `apply` CLAHE on the green channel which has been extracted using the statement `green = bgr[:,:,1]`..

Answer (score 0):

Print the name of the file prior to reading it with `imread`. That should give a fair idea about which file is being read by your program.

If you are sure that all the files in the directory are images, it's mostly likely caused by `desktop.ini`, a hidden file being read by imread. In that case, `imread` will return **None** and bgr will be of **NoneType**, which cannot be understood by `cvtColor` function.

Put a condition

```
if bgr:
    ...
```

**EDIT** : Probably, desktop.ini is not the issue. If it was, then you should have gotten an error at line 7 where you tried extracting the green channel. As pointed out by @sgarizvi, you are passing grayscale value to cvtColor.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I will check on this and get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

Try referring to this link, [open cv error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506126/open-cv-error-215-scn-3-scn-4-in-function-cvtcolor) . Changing the back slash to forward slash solved the error for me.

Comment: Well, the slash is not the problem indeed in my case, I am aware of the windows- python issue with slashes.. the problem is with performing image processing techniques on the single green channel alone from the given RGB image..