# Converting a Grayscale image to its original color format using Python

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, gray-code

Hi I am currently working on trying to convert a gray scale image to its original color format using Open CV in python.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('bw.jpg')

img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)


cv2.imwrite('gray_image.png',gray_image)
```

executing this produces an error:

```
error: (-215) scn == 1 && (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4) in function cv::cvtColor
```

Code in Python Imaging Library are also welcome.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: your code is missing.... and tell us what you tried soving it (e.g. follow page x, y, z).

Comment: I tried using this code of OpenCV:                                                                (cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)

Comment: include your code by modifying your question. This should be working example that produces errors. Even if its modified code from an example from OpenCV site. Thats fine, no worries. You're here to learn as others do. That way others can see what may be wrong. Just asking to code for you is not polite. No code > large risk removal of question and heavily down-voting.

Comment: Sorry for posting as it is. I have included the code.Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open cv error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506126/open-cv-error-215-scn-3-scn-4-in-function-cvtcolor)

Comment: @ZF007 I tried the link tat you posted but the grayscale images remain as it is. They are not converted to RGB format.

Comment: `gray_image = img` should do it because it seems not to be linked. See my answer.

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) what to do next.

Comment: As question poster besides having the right to select the best answer you are also allowed to up-vote one or more answers that helped you getting the problem fixed. (sometimes four distinct answers contribute in solving the issue and OP posts the solution as selfanswer but upvotes all four other answers as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are trying to convert a single channel image to 3 channel **grayscale** image. You are reading the image as `img = cv2.imread('bw.jpg')`, by default if you do not pass any param to `cv2.imread()`, then it reads a 3 channel image, irrespective of the original number of channels in the image. You may simply remove the line `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)`, as the `img` is already a 3 channel image with only grayscale information.

However if you are into this delusion that OpenCV has functionality of filling RGB colors to your grayscale image, then you are probably using wrong library. You can checkout other Open Source projects like [this](https://github.com/gustavla/autocolorize), which colorise your image using Deep Learning.

Answer (score 0):

See inline comment where mistake was made.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('bw.jpg')

x = img.shape

# check for color or gray-scale image type.
if x[3] == 3:

   print 'Got color image'
   # variable "gray_image" linked to result.
   gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)

   cv2.imwrite('gray_image.png',gray_image) # varname no longer img > gray_image.

else:
    print 'Got black/white, single channel image.'
    url = 'https://github.com//gustavla//autocolorize'
    print "Using ZdaR's posted solution from %s" % (url)
```

Comment: are you reading directly from camera...? Also, check if the image file is in the folder where it should be. To be sure make a folder on d-drive (windows) and replace "bw.jpg' with 'D:\test\myimage.jpg". If your image is black/white it might be already gray-scale... 1channel (1d) instead of 3 channels (3d) and then ZdaR is right.