# How to solve this cv2.cvtColor() error?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, django-models, computer-vision

Here is my code.

```
images, labels = loadWordsData('data/test_words/' + LANG + '_raw', loadGaplines=False)

for i in range(len(images)):
    printProgressBar(i, len(images))
    images[i] = imageNorm(
        cv2.cvtColor(images[i], cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB),
        60,
        border=False,
        tilt=True,
        hystNorm=True)
```

As I run this, following error comes.

> error: C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:11065: error: (-215) scn == 1 && (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4) in function cv::cvtColor

Thanks in advance .

Comment: The images are already 3/4 channel color images. Are you sure you don't mean `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY`?

Comment: Show the output of `images[i].shape`

Comment: test that the image is not empty (successfully loaded) and that it has exactly 1 channel before converting from gray to rgb.

Comment: Thanks all of you. I have resolve my problem. Images were already 3 channel color image.

Comment: I think you can find the answer on this discussion helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32598876/7871978