# TypeError: 'NoneType' and cv2.error in Python

Tags: python, opencv

Before getting to my question, I know that this is a very common question but depending on the code, might have multiple solutions so I would be very thankful if anyone could help me out.

I'm very new to Python and ML in general. So while running my create_gesture.py file, I get the NoneType error.
My code:

```
create_folder("gestures/" + str(g_id))
pic_no = 0
flag_start_capturing = False
frames = 0

while True:
    img = cam.read()[1]
    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
    imgCrop = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    dst = cv2.calcBackProject([imgHSV], [0, 1], hist, [0, 180, 0, 256], 1)
    disc = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (10, 10))
    cv2.filter2D(dst, -1, disc, dst)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(dst, (11, 11), 0)
    blur = cv2.medianBlur(blur, 15)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    thresh = cv2.merge((thresh, thresh, thresh))
    thresh = cv2.cvtColor(thresh, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thresh = thresh[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    contours = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[1]
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_gestures.py", line 120, in <module>
    store_images(g_id)
  File "create_gestures.py", line 70, in store_images
    imgCrop = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

**EDIT**:

Figured out that the integer value in the line

```
img = cam.read()[1]
```

was throwing the error. Was supposed to be 0 not 1. But now i get a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "create_gestures.py", line 121, in <module>
store_images(g_id)
File "create_gestures.py", line 72, in store_images
imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv 3.4.1\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:11109: error: (-215) depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5 in function cv::cvtColor
```

Answer (score 0):

NoneType means that instead of an instance of whatever Class or Object you think you're working with, you've actually got None. That usually means that an assignment or function call up above failed or returned an unexpected result.

Comment: Yeah i got that from the other similar questions on here but the problem is i can't seem to find where in my code did a function call fail exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Check what is in your variable `img` after this line of code: `img = cam.read()[1]`. Your `cam.read()[1]` probably returns `None`, you should check if that line of code works fine before you proceed.

Comment: yep it was indeed returning none. 
I think the index number is wrong so i changed it to `img = cam.read()[0]` 
and i'm now getting this error:

**cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.4.1\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:11109: error: (-215) depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5 in function cv::cvtColor**

Comment: @ShibeshDuwadi I do not have experience with the cv2 library but maybe that this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506126/open-cv-error-215-scn-3-scn-4-in-function-cvtcolor?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa