# Assertion Error while converting BGR to RGB using OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

So basically I'm converting images from BGR (used by OpenCV) to RGB (used by dlib) for some image vision stuff.

Here's some code:

```
for (i, imagePath) in enumerate(imagePaths):
    # load the input image and convert it from RGB (OpenCV ordering)
    # to dlib ordering (RGB)
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`
```

I'm getting the error
`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor` on `rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`

The full error is `cv2.error: /home/Ben/opencv-3.2.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:9716: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor`

Usually I know these errors are caused by incorrect image paths, but I've run the same code with different pictures, so it must be something with the pictures.

Looking at the picture properties, the only difference I can see is that the pics that don't work are 1080x1920 while the pictures that do work are a variety of sizes, such as 512x440 or 291x512.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Does the problem occur when you enter the path directly, without the for-loop? Is the path made with forward slashes? ([suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32598876/10699171))

Comment: @J.D. Yeah I was actually looking at that post when I originally was searching for an answer. The problem does occur when the image is put in manually, with this code: `import cv2

image = cv2.imread('/home/deeplearning/PycharmProjects/AltTSAStates/xc_pics/7516545584_IMG_4245.jpg', 0)
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` The path is entered with forward slashes.

Comment: @J.D. Also I think it might be an indicator how the error traces to the converting line, so it appears to read in correctly.

Comment: Can you try `cv2.imread([path], *1*)`? When loading an image, the code `0` means grayscale, which can't be used in a bgr-conversion.  [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html)

Comment: @J.D. I tried it with 1 (color), -1 (unchanged), and 4 (anycolor). I did, however, exclude the asterisks. Should they be included?

Comment: No, it was mean for emphasis. Can you try it with the image in the same folder as the script? Can you add `print(image.shape)` after `imread` and post the result?

Comment: @J.D. the pics are already in the same folder as the script. All of my results printing the shape are tuples, such as `(886, 590, 3)`, `(590, 886, 3)`, `(1280, 1920, 3)`, and `(1920, 1280, 3)`

Comment: Well, I see nothing out of the ordinary. Can you display the image without color conversion? If not, can you upload one of the problematic images?

Comment: @J.D. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PpvvT6cvhZkmHlflEK42ZbPkOF2pWlOq

Comment: It works just fine for me. But you mentioned that the problematic images are 1080x1920, these are smaller.